# How to Export the whole project in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, package.json

Say I have two projects A and B both written as Angular2 projects.

All I want to do is something similar to this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
```

or this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

In project B I want to be able to do this:

```
import { XComponent } from '@A/components'
```

Such that A is the first project and XComponent is a Component inside that project.

> Note: I am using angular-cli.

Comment: you can export (a.k.a. publish) a component, see for reference - https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination

Comment: @Roomy thank you but actually it didn't help me so much.